# Node.js: Watching a process in Linux for state changes

Tags: linux, bash, node.js, process

Are there files in the Linux filesystem that I could watch for changes on to monitor a process' status? In other words, is there a file that can be watched for fast process state change detection?

I would assume it'd be in the `/proc` directory, and what I'd like to do use use Node.js and the filesystem function `fs.watch()` to look for instant changes on a process' status. (Such as running, frozen, nonexistent, etc)

Is there a file that I can find a process' status in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The current process state can be found in `/proc/$PID/stat`. This is the third field from `man proc`:

> ```
>   state %c    One character from the string "RSDZTW"  where
>               R  is running, S is sleeping in an interrupt‐
>               ible wait, D is  waiting  in  uninterruptible
>               disk  sleep,  Z  is  zombie,  T  is traced or
>               stopped (on a signal), and W is paging.
> ```

Whether you can use file system watch functions on it is another matter, as /proc files aren't real files, but rather handles that generate data on demand.

Comment: It'll "work" (in that it won't fail), but it won't always **work** (in that it won't always do anything useful).

Comment: ...and in /proc/$PID/status - you could find the State human-readable.